# What should a slide-down / pop-up login form do on success?

Tags: php, javascript, session, authentication, session-state

I've a login form like this:

[image: login form]

The form calls a PHP script to interact with my database.

#### On successful submission of the login form, what should happen?

Should I log the user in (add variables to session) in my PHP and update elements on the current page (in my JavaScript) to reflect the fact the user is now logged in? Is too much hassle because the login form is accessible in *every* page?
Should I just force a reload/redirect? If so, then when & where should I set that the user is logged in? What if the reload/redirect fails?
Any other options?

Answer (score 0):

seemless approach would be to call a .click() on the hide button on success: of the ajax call (which is assuming what you're using)..

```
success: function(data){
    $('#hide-button').click();
    // added this, shows "Welcome back $username" in a div called user info.. 
    // just create a user info div and leave it blank.
    $('#user-info').append("Welcome back<strong>, "+data.username+"</strong>");
},
// you could also use error: to keep the window open and display errors..
error: function(data){
   $('#errors').append("Your Errors are: "+data.errors");
}
```

Comment: Where would the session state be changed? With this implementation also, things on the page will still reflect an unauthenticated state... i.e. nav items `login` & `create account` will still be there for example

Comment: Reload the homepage, after setting the username session variable, in your homepage you will be checking that variable, if set then display username.

Comment: U will need to reload those items. Using jquery.

Comment: Also check into the session plugin that allows u to set sessions and cookies .. might be another approach.

Comment: would be great to get a confirmed answer on this if my response answered your question.